# How to use integrals to evaluate a function?

Tags: calculus, integration

Textbooks often show:

$f(x)=\int f'(x)\ dx$

But how do we evaluate $f(x)$ at a specific x, let's say $f(2)$?

Let's say

$f(x)=x^2 ,\     f'(x) = 2x$

then $f(3) = 9$

but on the right hand side, shall we do $\int_{-\infty}^3\ f'(x)\ dx$? That doesn't work...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you find a *definite* integral, you have to have upper and lower limits. Visually, your $f'(x)$ is a graph and the integral of that is the area under the graph. So to actually calculate the area, you (usually) need to cut it off on the left and the right: this is a and b in the picture below.

[image: integral as an area]

Also remember, if you take the derivative of f(x) (and the derivative exists) you will get one valid function, but integrating f'(x) gets you an infinite number of functions that all differ by a constant. This is the *indefinite* integral; for example, $\int2xdx$ can get you $x^2$, $x^2 +1$, $x^2 + 2$, and so forth.

Comment: so f(x)=∫f′(x) dx is more of a special notation, I can't actually use it to evaluate the function at a point.

Comment: Ah ok, just saw your edit. That makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Haha, thanks! And I like the way you describe a "special notation": I myself see it as a sort of description, rather than a definition, of $f(x)$. Cool!

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be a $\mathcal{C}^1$ function, textbooks are saying that in this case, $f$ is an antiderivative of $f'$.

However, one has: $$f(b)-f(a)=\int_{a}^bf'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x.$$

I would like to point out, that in your case $f(3)=9$, not $4$.

Comment: Yes, thanks, fixed ;)

Answer (score 0):

Actually $f(x)+c= \int f'(x) dx$ where $c$ is sn arbitrary constant More specifically, we can define $f(x)= \int_{a}^x f'(x)dx$ using the fundamental theorem of calculus, where $f(a)= 0$ if such an $a$ exists. If such an $a$ does not exist then it is not possible to have a closed form as desired.